# Cron error: /bin/sh: 1: 6: not found

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run the Cron Job to do a very simple test.
I wanted the command `echo "hello"` to be run from cron.

However, everytime I run it I get the following error:

```
Return-Path: <bitnami@ip-172-26-15-128.eu-west-3.compute.internal>
X-Original-To: bitnami
Delivered-To: bitnami@ip-172-26-15-128.eu-west-3.compute.internal
Received: by ip-172-26-15-128.eu-west-3.compute.internal (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id A8DA81F6631; Sat, 17 Aug 2019 23:32:01 +0200 (CEST)
From: root@ip-172-26-15-128.eu-west-3.compute.internal (Cron Daemon)
To: bitnami@ip-172-26-15-128.eu-west-3.compute.internal
Subject: Cron <bitnami@ip-172-26-15-128> 6 echo "hello"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/bitnami>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=bitnami>
Message-Id: <20190817213201.A8DA81F6631@ip-172-26-15-128.eu-west-3.compute.internal>
Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2019 23:32:01 +0200 (CEST)

/bin/sh: 1: 6: not found
```

This is how my crontab looks like:

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
* * * * * 6 echo "hello"
```

I tried to change the shell to bash but the problem persists. I also checked that both `sh` and `bash` are present in `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` location.

I can't figure out why it's happening.

Comment: Looks like `6 echo "hello"` is your command. What does the crontab look like? Please do not paste it in comments, [edit] the question instead.

Comment: updated the crontab structure in question (check bold section please)

Answer (score 2):

Such a stupid mistake. I had 1 `*` extra. Instead of `* * * * 6`, I entered `* * * * * 6`.